# python regex with specific requirements

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import re
logins = [u"idr.kjh-kf0", u"8idr.kjh-kf0", u"idr.kjh-kfй", u"Idr.kjh*kf0", u"inhdrkjghrdkgjhdrkgjhrgkj"]
regex = re.compile(r"[^\d{1}]+[\w{1}|\d{1}]$")

for login in logins:
    if regex.match(login):
        print login.encode('utf-8')
```

And i need to check every string by regex, that matches these parameters:

- first symbol is only letter
- last symbol is letter or digit
- in the middle of all that allowed letters, digits, dot and hyphen.
- total length is 20 symbols

i request for regex that match these parameters

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: updated. i need the regex that match requested parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) we can figure out:

- First symbol is a letter: `^[A-Za-z]`
- Last symbol is a letter or a digit: `[0-9A-Za-z]$`
- Middle letters, digits, dot and hyphen: `[0-9A-Za-z\-\.]`
- Total length is 20 symbols: `x{,20}` means x 0 to 20 times

Now just assemble this: `re.compile('^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z.-]{,18}[0-9A-Za-z]$')`.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that i'm not smart enough to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-z0-9A-Z.-]{18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/2